# How can I change the Xcode 6 Device screenshot destination?

Tags: xcode, screenshot, xcode6

It saves it to the desktop but I want to change the location it goes to.

Is there [something like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screenshot-in-os-x-lion) out there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) or [AppleScript folder actions](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/) to watch for files matching certain name or other attributes and move them automatically into a folder of your choosing. Probably not the answer you’re looking for, but unless someone finds a hidden preferences key to change that path, it may be your best option.

Comment: Has anyone had success with such a script?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to make without writing code using Hazel, I think. But I haven't tried it.